# javascript object method recursively call

Tags: javascript, recursion, bind

My question is related to the play function. How can I call this `Player.play()` method recursively call?
`Using this.player.play()` is not working.

```
function Player(playlist){
  open:function(){
    //doing some stuff here
  }
  play:function(){
    if(picture){
      //document.getElementById("img").src =playlist[n]

    }

  }
}
var player = new Player([link1, link2, link3]);
document.getElementById("play-btn").addEventListener("click", player.play())
```

Comment: Why would you do that? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Your code is a non working mixture... Could you show your real code?.

Comment: You probably need to call `this.play()`  instead of `Player.play()` from within the play method of the `Player` if you want to make it recursive. `this` would refer to the `Player` __instance__ within the scope of the play method.

Comment: `document.getElementById("play-btn").addEventListener("click", player.play())` <-- wrong

Comment: I can not show my real code, because its more than 600 lines, especially this 2 function also arround 200 lines,

Comment: "I created an object" - not with that code you didn't. [All you created were errors](https://jsfiddle.net/15xaes3c/).

Comment: I want this recursion, because the player is prepare for av.player, and the play method opens the links with av-player

Comment: Its a special tizen projekt, and I did created that object.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "recursively"? What _exactly_ is your expected outcome?

Comment: the open function setup some listeners like onbuffering etc,
The play function checks if its  a picture or a video to able to play with avplayer

Comment: @Andy I want to itterate on the playlist, and in the play function i want to check if its a picture, or video. If a picture, than just grab it in the HTML, If its a video, I want to open it with avplayer.

Answer (score 1):

At first, your syntax is a comvination of a function and a class, you may use a class like:

```
 class Player {
   constructor(links,element){
     this.images = links;
     this.position = 0;
     this.element = element;
   }
   //...
}
```

Then you can set an Interval that shows one image after another:

```
next(){
 this.element.src =  this.images[
    this.position = (this.position + 1) % this.images.length
 ];
}

play(){
 if(!this.interval) this.interval = setInterval(_=>this.next(),1000);
}
stop(){
  clearInterval(this.interval);
  this.interval = null;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
 var player = new Player(
   ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"],
   document.getElementById("img")
 );

 document
   .getElementById("play-btn")
   .addEventListener("click", _=>player.play());
```

Comment: Thank you, this code seems like usefull, Im gona try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do recursive there should be a stop condition.

`this.player.play()` is not correct.Should be `this.play()`

Comment: Not working sadly :/